How to Manually Import an API into WSO2 API Manager Without an OpenAPI Definition?
I'm trying to avoid connecting directly to the API for safety, so I want to use a middleware. However, I need to import the destination API to facilitate the connection between the client app and the API.The only issue I have is that WSO2 is asking for an OpenAPI file definition, which is not possible because my API does not have one.
I read about create the middleware wso2 from scratch and connect the endpoints from the middleware to the others from my api, but is not working

Any issues you are facing when you have configured the API from scratch? What is the API Manager version that you are using and are you seeing any errors during the creation or deployment?

You can follow these resources to expose the backend API through API manager.
You need to provide the correct backend and set the correct resources. Refer create rest API document. Once API is created you need to deploy the api to the gateway and publish it to the portal. You could use the publisher portal test console to test the API.
